# Is there any relation between Pixies' "Where Is My Mind?" and Aliotta Haynes Jeremiah "Lake Shore Drive"?

Tags: rock

Is there any relation between Pixies' [*Where Is My Mind?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49FB9hhoO6c) and Aliotta Haynes Jeremiah's [*Lake Shore Drive*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0saZiLV7-7E)?

I ask because the piano riff is pretty similar among the songs. And I can't shake the feeling the piano in *Lake Shore Drive* came from *Where Is My Mind?*.

Comment: They have both a similar chord progression?

Comment: That's how it sounds to me

Answer (score 1):

While it may sound like a similar chord progression - that isn't uncommon in music. There are only so many keys and chord progressions. Black Francis could have heard that song before and it stuck with him subconciously, but neither of these two songs are related or exclusive to that one chord progression. If I'm not mistaken it isn't the same progression - just similar.